# infoblox Cannot add records to a zone that is not authoritative

Tags: domain-name-system, infoblox

We manage the dns for `example.exm.uk`

I am trying to add an internal A Record

```
url : www.server.example.exm.uk
ip  : 1.2.3.4
```

I get an error message "Cannot add records to a zone that is not authoritative"

when i goto dns home i have an entry

```
2.1.in-addr.arpa which is Authoritative
```

Also, I have hundreds of other internal A records pointing to 1.2.3.4

Comment: It's hard to tell based on the information you've given us, which includes a non-existent domain that you do not own. (`exm.uk`) There is likely a `NS` record named "server" in this zone, or some form of typo. We won't be able to tell without a list of records in this domain, and the exact name of the record you are attempting to add. (without redaction, so that we can identify the typo)

Comment: This is old, I know, but so strange. You talk about `example.exm.uk`, but show something about the reverse IP zone `2.1.in-addr.arpa`. Why do you care about it, when your problem is with completely different zone? A DNS server can perfectly be authoritative for some zones and not to be authoritative for others. Forget about it and back to topic: is your server really authoritative for `example.exm.uk`?